# How to register TSF with Windows Desktop speech engine

Tags: speech, scratchpad

Here is my code to initialize and register with TSF:

```
::OleInitialize(NULL);

HRESULT hr=CoCreateInstance(CLSID_TF_ThreadMgr,NULL,CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,IID_ITfThreadMgr,(void **)&pThreadMgr);
if (FAILED(hr) || pThreadMgr==null) return;

hr=pThreadMgr->Activate(&ClientId);
if (FAILED(hr)) return;

hr=pThreadMgr->CreateDocumentMgr(&pDocumentMgr);
if (FAILED(hr) || pDocumentMgr==null) return;


pTextStore=new CTextStore();   // create my ITextStoreACP store

hr=pDocumentMgr->CreateContext(ClientId,0,reinterpret_cast<ITextStoreACP *>pTextStore,&pContext,&EditCookie);
if (FAILED(hr) || pContext==null) goto END;

hr=pDocumentMgr->Push(pContext);
if (FAILED(hr)) return;
```

At the end of this code, my TextStore interface gets the GetTextView,GetStatus and GetWnd calls.  However, no calls are received to the SetText() or any other methods when I speak into the Microphone.  The default dictation scratchpad shows up instead.  I don't want the scratchpad to show up.  I need the text to be routed to my TextStore.  Do I need to register the TextStoreACP interface with speech engine?  What am I missing here? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The application window needs to be specified as the focus window to the document manager:

```
pThreadMgr->AssociateFocus(hWnd, pDocumentMgr, &pPrevDocumentMgr);
```

After this call,  TSF starts routing speech calls to the ITextStoreACP interface.